# How to Configure Your Domain linked to Firebase Hosting, and maintain mail access (DNS records)

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

There are already many posts on the web to help you connect your custom domain to Firebase.

In fact, if you have enough experience, you wouldn't even need a guide...it's that simple.

What is NOT commonly known is that, with your default hosting configuration (for example a cPanel hosted service)... Once you've reconfigured the domain's A-record to the Firebase IP, everything pointing to that domain is redirected to the new IP.

For example:

A => yourfunkydomain.com => **yourFirebaseIP**

A => ftp.yourfunkydomain.com => *yourHostingServiceIP*

All good...

But what about your MX record?

MX => yourfunkydomain.com

CNAME => mail.yourfunkydomain.com => yourfunkydomain.com

You won't be getting mails any time soon...

The Fix:

MX => mail.yourfunkydomain.com

CNAME becomes A => mail.yourfunkydomain.com => *yourHostingServiceIP*

So keep in mind, any other records needs to be updated to their own respective IP's.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I just did that let me wait for the domain to propagate and  I will  give a response if this works

Comment: This worked for me. However, I did have to reconfigure my POP3 settings for the mail client.